# Asp.net Web Api 2 - how to get access_token from C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, access-token

I am preparing a C# Api for my website. When I call the following code to login and get the access token, response.IsSuccessStatusCode is ok (200), but I could not find any access_token from the response. I assume the access token comes through response body, but could not find a proper function to get the response body.

```
var token = new Dictionary<string, string> { {"grant_type", "password"}, {"username", "administrator@parkatstreet.com"}, 
{"password", "OOKKUUc564$"},};

var tknModel = new FormUrlEncodedContent(token);

var resp = await client.PostAsync("http://parkatstreet.com/Token", tknModel);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string responseStream = response.Headers.ToString();
}
```

The response I am getting is:

> {StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   Pragma: no-cache
>   X-SourceFiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRcUGF5cm9sbEFwaVxEYml0UGF5cm9sbEFwaVxEYml0UGF5cm9sbEFwaVxUb2tlbg==?=
>   Cache-Control: no-cache   Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2015 05:19:10 GMT
>   Set-Cookie:
>   .AspNet.Cookies=lgQKnoQzwpUbpE9PpVm9L71rlBEBwG_oA4VT89oowNoynkdpHRfGj6Lt92XJ5N1Pnmfv_FUQ07EVuLOLpjiuLtnoqOE2SqAFvXr7tMQmoXlU-pvf8KwkTx6Fl_TyC-VrCPOoOcxEAolBcN3oHXHYcjYPaqmZpQA-mQqcjwxIumXd6eVEHfEZtRj3EiVLS0schzD9TG8IcPq3JkzEQpqu_srEBKbJQ8zIJX6TCfkFK3cvGGJ-6cbV8lIJcPke8ahnc_icDkPKnlfzZZEEZEzeamYX3u1g1R50bj-y01T0JXQLyqGK-EpzjiLwqeO5yv1-yJ_1GQrqv46lomu51WTY_oMIXvGTNEU8wurJtN2XdpBLKg1X79VQxqunniKpYGtYN1wq-sl-RPiFLz9Cnh21yD1ogSNJoWEutyOP3lpCvZp50cAktDqB-swG92_a8f6OPzFHSG0yUq01Ro1YFJNBljP5eWT8r9wGqP1ZlDHLAmQ;
>   path=/; HttpOnly   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
>   Content-Length: 688   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>   Expires: -1 }}

And the response I expect is:

> {
>       "access_token": "4b-KAhg7QNMyHNVXFBUFBq5NJvlw7_JmaXZl1SDLIi6sMl5kTh8EfnvNTNa5iUwQuiNSk2Il6nUxheAJ64rroYYF-woWcQ9l8J8g56IuCApUNJWzD31eyJrOBI2yzZcTFY8X0GqpidYhZNvTHsn4PNwOZAHAebBK64yMstb9-66kdgp-vSgvCvH1tA45drlWVuNsjmsX6EHg5WlDFJsPhnDL7Lz4sSYxtFF8ipZvAEoxJ-dGsQHRsIAygY934nrLdYP7saDCAAqlzvUoWspYIO2B9kyyzoYREjb3Y9ik8MEmuGZgk-hzAWkTRMh51tUn0wknMPVsDve_OYdX9qZlMoxDEXJjGhPmxMKd_o2AdGkPU31OTW6Y3JkQZVdTTHqUuCWMTWctkImvIpSRlpwfc71qRltbp1wy7SjHQdpeYC8ZBcjO-B6NImkxjM_yb2BVKM8TrXeqdYrRcKBer6RjpgMCwlha9oH8_yyFNqbw-U1YcrKLvIfJPqjJ45K37bkn",
>       "token_type": "bearer",
>       "expires_in": 1209599,
>       "userName": "administrator@parkatstreet.com",
>       ".issued": "Thu, 24 Sep 2015 04:45:59 GMT",
>       ".expires": "Thu, 08 Oct 2015 04:45:59 GMT" }

Comment: do you have control over the server?

Comment: yes. Both are my code. Also please note that I get the correct response when I call from javascript as shown below.                                              var login = function ()
        {
            var url = "/Token";
            var data = $("#userData").serialize();
            data = data + "&grant_type=password";
            $.post(url, data)
                .success(saveAccessToken)
                .always(showResponse);
            return false;
        };

Comment: In that case,make sure you're setting the `access_token` in response header.

Comment: Token is a part of OWIN middle-ware, so could not keep any break point there

Comment: Can you show your api from where you are returning access_token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new Console Application and use the following code:

```
namespace APIClientConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // TODO - Send HTTP requests              
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:24780/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));                
                // HTTP POST                
                var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "bnk"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "bnk123")                    
                };
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("token", content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseStream);   
                    Console.ReadLine();                 
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

You can read more at the following link

[Calling a Web API From a .NET Client in ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you use javascript to access to response content (or body as you call it)

```
$.post(url, data).success(saveAccessToken).always(showResponse);
```

In C# you access can get the content with

```
string responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

If you have `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` referenced you can parse the content with

```
ResponseType result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ResponseType>();
```